# Can this differential equation be solved analytically?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, numerical-methods

I have this equation:

$$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}=\frac{1+\left(\frac{dz}{dx}\right)^2}{M(z)}\frac{dM}{dz}$$

Where $$M(z)=A+B\text{ log(z)}+Cz$$

And $z|_{x=0}$, $\frac{dz}{dx}|_{x=0}$ are known, and $A,B,C$ are constants, also known.

My question is, whether this equation can be solved analytically, or if not could someone hint me to what is the best way to reach an accurate numerical solution? I know I should write down any of my own attempts at this, but I have no idea how to start it, and to me it looks like it is not possible to reach analytical solution.

Comment: The equation can be written $\frac{z'z''}{1+z'^2} = \frac{d\log M }{dx}$ which is integrable.

Comment: Once you get to $\left(\frac{dz}{dx}\right)^2=cM^2-1$ you can integrate by [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables). Since $\frac{dz}{dx}=\sqrt{cM^2-1}$, then $\frac{dz}{cM^2-1}=dx$. Integrating you get that $\int\frac{dz}{\sqrt(cM^2-1)}=x+D$, for some constant $D$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce the order of the differential equation at least:
$$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}=\frac{1+\left(\frac{dz}{dx}\right)^2}{M(z)}\frac{dM}{dz}$$
$$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}=\frac{1+\left(\frac{dz}{dx}\right)^2}{M(z)}\frac{dM} {dx}\frac {dx}{dz}$$
$$\frac {dz}{dx}\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}=\frac{1+\left(\frac{dz}{dx}\right)^2}{M(z)}\frac{dM} {dx}$$
Substitute $w=z'$:
$$ww'=\frac{1+w^2}{M}\frac{dM}{dx}$$
$$w \frac {dw}{dx}=\frac{1+w^2}{M}\frac{dM}{dx}$$
Separate and integrate:
$$\frac {2w dw}{1+w^2}=2\frac{dM}{M}$$
$$\ln |w^2+1|=2\ln|M|+k$$
$$w^2+1=cM^2$$
$$\left(\frac {dz}{dx}\right )^2=cM^2-1$$

Comment: Thank you, I will take it from here.

Comment: @Scavenger23 you're welcome.

Comment: One thing I have a problem understanding though. What happened to $dx$ in the last line?

Comment: It's gone by simplification since you had it on both sides On RHS $dM/dx$ and on LHS $w'=dw/dx$ @Scavenger23. Integrate then write $w=dz/dx$ and see what you can do either integrate or use numerical merhods.

Comment: @Scavenger23 I added some lines I hope ot's more clear now.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get to that solution too. Now I am thinking how to solve for z.

Comment: If you cant manage to integrate you can use numerical method @Scavenger23. The function $M(z)$ is not that easy that's why it's so hard to integrate. And now it's an integration problem not a differential equation problem.